# How do you use the postgresql WITH in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In postgresql one can read data from a "with" I want to know how to make use of that in rails without putting the whole query in raw sql..

Here's a sample query: it is totally contrived for this question.

```
with tasks as (select 1 as score, tasks.* from tasks)
select 1 from tasks where id > 10 order by tasks.score, tasks.id
```

In my real example score is calculated not just 1 but for the example it works.

Here's how I imagine the code would look

```
Task.with('tasks as (select 1 as score, tasks.* from tasks)')
    .where('id > 10')
    .order(score)
    .order(id)
```

I don't really like using the "with" because it is PG specific, but I really need to sort on the calculated value. I tried a view but the creation of the view in PG requires the exact fields, and I don't want other coders to have to alter the view when they alter the source table.

I do really want to be able to chain this.

Comment: A common table expression (CTE, starting with WITH) isn't a PostgreSQL thing, it's standard SQL. It's also supported by DB2, SQL Server and SQLite, don't know about other brands, but I'm pretty sure it is supported by many.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is supported in pure *ActiveRecord* without dropping down to raw *SQL*.

However, there is an add-on, [postgres_ext](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2013/09/06/postgres_ext-adds-rank-and-common-table-expressions.html) which, among other things, adds *CTE* support for use with *ActiveRecord*. I haven't used this add-on myself (I would prefer to drop down into raw *SQL* in this situation), but it looks like it would allow the chaining behavior you are looking for.

Once you've installed that, you'd want to use its `from_cte` method to define the *CTE* (the `WITH` statement), and then chain however you'd like to filter, sort, etc.

So I think the code would look something like this:

```
Task.from_cte('tasks', Task.where('id > 10')).order('tasks.score, tasks.id')
```

Note that the chaining starts after the `from_cte` call has completed on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that results.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Well, you could add more to the chaining within the `from_cte`, I think -- it really depends on what you want the *CTE* to be. You could certainly also filter by user in the `where` method such that the CTE just contained a single user's tasks.

Comment: Ugg.. so it would query the database for all the records, before limiting.. so if my user table had say 200k uses and I wanted the tasks for 1 of them I'd get all the tasks through the relation?